# how to use gpu programming with tensorflow on a m1 pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

i wanted to reprogram my tensorflow project so that the program runs on the gpu. For this i installed tensorflow according to the following instructions:

https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/install-tensorflow-on-mac-m1-m2-with-gpu-support-c404c6cfb580

i have not changed my program. the model used and the training process is as follows:

```
# Recurent NN
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(len(data[0]), 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dense, activation='softmax')
])

print(model.summary())


# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(data_train, labels_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(data_test, labels_test))
```

Unfortunately i get the following output during the training process:

```
2023-03-09 20:53:23.670721: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x143695190
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaanerbay/PycharmProjects/tftest/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
  File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'StatefulPartitionedCall_212' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/PycharmProjects/tftest/main.py", line 13, in <module>
      model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1027, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 527, in minimize
      self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1140, in apply_gradients
      return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 634, in apply_gradients
      iteration = self._internal_apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1166, in _internal_apply_gradients
      return tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1216, in _distributed_apply_gradients_fn
      distribution.extended.update(
    File "/Users/kaanerbay/miniconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall_212'
could not find registered platform with id: 0x143695190
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_212}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_23355]
```

Comment: Question: is the M1 Pro GPU compliant with TF's standards? Once upon a time it needed a CUDA compatible architecture.

Comment: I haven't used it but there are some official Apple docs for TF on Apple Silicon here https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Comment: I have now re-installed everything and installed it according to the instructions from apple. Unfortunately, I now get a new error message. I update the upper error code in the new one.